# Show that there in no value such that f(x) = 1/x is continuous at the point 0 using the epsilon/delta-definition

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove, that there does not exist a $c \in \mathbb{R}$, such that

\begin{equation}
f(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{x}, \text{ for } x \neq 0\\
c, \text{ for } x = 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
is continuous for $x_0 = 0$

Using sequences I solved this the following way:
Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} := (\frac{1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}$\ {$0$} and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = 0.$
Then, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{1/n} = \infty$
Hence, the limit is unequal to $c = f(x_0)$ for any $c \in \mathbb{R}.$

**I was wondering how to prove this using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-method**
Here is what I came up with so far:
$\exists \epsilon > 0$, $\forall \delta > 0$ , there $\exists x \in [x_0 -x] < \delta$, s.d. $|f(x_0) - f(x)| \geq \epsilon.$

Thus, in this case, we need to shwo that
$\exists x \in $ $[-x] < \delta$, s.d. $|c - \frac{1}{x}| \geq \epsilon$. Now, let $\epsilon := \frac{1}{2}$.
As $x$ becomes very small, the expression $|c - \frac{1}{x}|$ grows to infinity and is thus greater then $\frac{1}{2}$.

**Is there a way to make my last sentence more mathematical?** Can I somehow get rid of the $c$ or use a different argument to stick closer to the $\epsilon-\delta$-definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just find the value of $x$ explicitly. When $c >0$ Note that for $0< x < 1/c$ we have $|c - 1/x| = 1/x - c$, so we want to show that $1/x - c > 1/2$ for some $x$ in this range. But then we just solve:
$$1/x > 1/2 +c$$
and thus any
$$x < \frac{1}{1/2 + c}$$
works, that is, choose $0<x < \min(\delta, \frac{1}{1/2 + c})$.

When $c < 0$ follow the same through for $1/c < x < 0$, and when $c = 0$ it's easier.

Comment: sweet, thank you lots!!